# ID of the image remains same in all the devices that the app is installed

Tags: java, android

In my application i will be changing the images dynamically in the image view so with the help of ID of the image i am changing.

```
int id = R.Drawable.sample_img
```

So I want to know whether the id of the img (sample_img) will be same in other device that is installed or the id varies depending upon the devices

Can any one help me.

Comment: What exactly are you referring to as "changing the images dynamically"? Are you going to set `R.Drawable.sample_img1` or `R.Drawable.sample_img2` or `R.Drawable.sample_img3` dynamically? or you want to get image from url dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R` is the dynamically generated class, created during Android build process.

`R.Drawable.sample_img` may vary, depending on build. Simple rebuild will change it.

But `R.Drawable.sample_img` stays same after build.

For all devices using **same** apk file it's value stays same. In **different** apk versions it will be different.